# Adding a font in Telerik RadEditor

Tags: asp.net, fonts, telerik, radeditor

I am a new user to sitefinity and I want to add 30 fonts to be used throughout one theme which can be interchanged through the frontend. I already applied it through the style.css of the theme however it did not alter the widget font. So I got creative and over-road all the contentblock headings however I want 30 fonts and I don't h1-h30 headings and having to guess which one is which so I started editing the RadEditor. I want the fonts to show up in the dropdown font menu. I have tried editing the StandardToolsFile.xml did not work, I have tried the C# (but unsure exactly where to input it so I might have put it in wrong), I have tried the ASP.NET which worked but it didn't go in the content block and wouldn't disappear from the page.

XML File **strong text**

```
<root>    
<tools>    
    <tool name="FontName" />  
</tools>    
<fontNames>    
    <item name="Arial" />    
    <item name="Arial Narrow" />    
    <item name="Arial Black" />  
</fontNames>
</root>
```

C#

```
RadEditor1.FontNames.Add("Arial");
RadEditor1.FontNames.Add("Arial Narrow");
RadEditor1.FontNames.Add("Arial Black");
```

**ASP.NET (worked it was inserted into the master and trired seperately in an ascx)**

```
<telerik:RadEditor RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadEditor1">
<FontNames>
    <telerik:EditorFont Value="Arial" />
    <telerik:EditorFont Value="Arial Narrow" />
    <telerik:EditorFont Value="Arial Black" />
</FontNames>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

I've attached photos of my [content block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBwIR.png) and my [appearance settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbfK8.png). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add fonts to ContentBlock you need to go to Administration > Settings > Text Editor and edit the Default Tool Set - which is an xml that resembles the RadEditor's [ToolsFile.xml](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/functionality/toolbars/dropdowns/fonts#adding-fontnames-to-toolsfilexml).

For instance, you can add these:

```
<fontNames>    
    <item name="Arial" />    
    <item name="Arial Narrow" />    
    <item name="Arial Black" />  
</fontNames>
```

Then save and you can see the fonts in your Content Blocks

Comment: I can not find the Text Editor in the Basic Settings

Comment: --> Update: Found it under global settings in basic settings

Comment: Where to store the css & font files in sitefinity, the names are in the dropdown but not working

Comment: If you are using a Theme - then you can define all your styles there. 
Otherwise, if you have your own Master page - then you can manually add your css files there.

Comment: I have tried adding them to the styles and the master page, the fonts I want will still not load but a font (SF Comic Script) is loading properly and I took it out (Style, master, deleted file from sitefinity) to see if I can determine the problem but it is still loading properly well the others are not. Do you have an idea of what is happening?